# Is the "effective power" issue in iOS due to a memory managment bug?

Tags: ios, memory-management, unicode, utf-8

The recent "effective power" bug in iOS is a text message filled with specific characters ("لُصّبُلُلصّبُررً ॣ ॣh ॣ ॣ 冗") iOS bug that when sent and viewed as a notification on iOS causes the phone to reset.

My question is whether this is due to some bug in iOS's memory management. As far as my understanding goes, when iOS devices receive data it is in the form of NSData. The text is usually in the form of UTF-8 (unicode 8-bit encoding) and then the UTF-8 data is parsed by the iOS system using whatever unicode library iOS uses.

Is it possible that somewhere in this conversion, these characters, since they are so uncommon and have really long unicode signatures, cause some sort of buffer overflow? Then iOS would probably kill this process in order to avoid any sort of system failure by resetting the phone.

Here's a link to an article regarding the topic:

http://www.techradar.com/us/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/this-single-text-message-is-crashing-people-s-iphones-here-s-the-fix-1295019

Any replies/insight would be helpful.

Comment: This isn't an issue I'm familiar with. Perhaps including a link to an article on the topic would be helpful.

Comment: I added a link. Thanks for the edit Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article on a famous (in Russia :) Russian IT site.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/259007/

The author investigated this issue, below you can see the crash stacktrace he got. Here is his conclusion (I translated the part I think is important for the discussion):

> The last documented function call is `CTLineCreateWithAttributedString`, which gives us nothing. 
>   The crash itself occurs inside of `CopyFromStorage(TRunGlue&, long)` method, and (judging by the assembly code) it happens during copying of a byte array of length `long n` from one part of memory to another `(movq 0x90(%rax), %rdx)`.
>
> I suppose it occurs because of some differences in calculating length of arabic strings in two different parts of the program. I might be mistaken, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xf611cd, 0x00000001120ce5f3 CoreText`CopyFromStorage(TRunGlue&, long) + 28, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x90)
        frame #0: 0x00000001120ce5f3 CoreText`CopyFromStorage(TRunGlue&, long) + 28
        frame #1: 0x00000001120ce283 CoreText`TRunGlue::RotateGlyphs(CFRange, long) + 527
        frame #2: 0x000000011212b71b CoreText`OpenTypeShapingEngine::ApplyScriptShaping(unsigned int*) + 465
        frame #3: 0x00000001120d0201 CoreText`TOpenTypeMorph::ApplyShapingEngine(OTL::GSUB&, OTL::GlyphLookups&, unsigned int*, CFRange, bool&) + 739
        frame #4: 0x00000001120d1007 CoreText`TOpenTypeMorph::ShapeGlyphs(bool&) + 331
        frame #5: 0x0000000112056c4e CoreText`TShapingEngine::ShapeGlyphs(TLine&, TCharStream const*) + 264
        frame #6: 0x000000011205c48b CoreText`TTypesetter::FinishEncoding(std::__1::tuple*, unsigned int, unsigned char> const&, TLine&, signed char) + 127
        frame #7: 0x0000000112070586 CoreText`TTypesetterAttrString::Initialize(__CFAttributedString const*) + 674
        frame #8: 0x000000011207029a CoreText`TTypesetterAttrString::TTypesetterAttrString(__CFAttributedString const*) + 158
        frame #9: 0x000000011205d79f CoreText`CTLineCreateWithAttributedString + 63
        frame #10: 0x0000000110c6d8bd UIFoundation`__NSStringDrawingEngine + 18744
        frame #11: 0x0000000110c68f5f UIFoundation`-[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 198
        frame #12: 0x000000010e875788 UIKit`-[UIButton _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 946
        frame #13: 0x000000010ec2466d UIKit`-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) intrinsicContentSize] + 37
        frame #14: 0x000000010ec24b6c UIKit`-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 33
        frame #15: 0x000000010ec24930 UIKit`-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 422
        frame #16: 0x000000010ec2bd25 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 162
        frame #17: 0x000000010e87521b UIKit`-[UIButton updateConstraints] + 2925
        frame #18: 0x000000010ec2b346 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 242
        frame #19: 0x000000010ec2b53e UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
        frame #20: 0x000000010e0bd354 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
        frame #21: 0x000000010ec2b2ed UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
        frame #22: 0x000000010d9ef1be Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
        frame #23: 0x000000010ec2b53e UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
        frame #24: 0x000000010ec2ba0e UIKit`__60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 96
        frame #25: 0x000000010d9ef1be Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
        frame #26: 0x000000010ec2b6d6 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 231
        frame #27: 0x000000010ec2bdde UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 146
        frame #28: 0x000000010e623a3d UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 114
        frame #29: 0x000000010e62fa2b UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
        frame #30: 0x0000000111e08ec2 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
        frame #31: 0x0000000111dfd6d6 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 380
        frame #32: 0x0000000111dfd546 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
        frame #33: 0x0000000111d69886 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 242
        frame #34: 0x0000000111d6aa3a QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 462
        frame #35: 0x000000010e5ada2d UIKit`-[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
        frame #36: 0x000000010e5ae6f1 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2648
        frame #37: 0x000000010e5ad0d5 UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
        frame #38: 0x0000000110d835e5 FrontBoardServices`__31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
        frame #39: 0x000000010e0ea41c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
        frame #40: 0x000000010e0e0165 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
        frame #41: 0x000000010e0dff25 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2389
        frame #42: 0x000000010e0df366 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
        frame #43: 0x000000010e5acb42 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 413
        frame #44: 0x000000010e5af900 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
      * frame #45: 0x000000010d91ed0f Islam`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff522e1330) + 111 at main.m:14
        frame #46: 0x000000011076e145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: Supposedly the bug is caused by the fact that the text contains both characters from languages which are read (displayed) from left to right and from right to left, e.g. English + Arabic.

Comment: @Sulthan, I don't think that's right cause left to right + right to left text is very common and only this specific text yields that result. Also Anton, thanks for the answer. You may be correct. It may specifically have something to do an error in the way register memory is allocated and deallocated during the transfer of the bytearray, but again I don't specialize in this stuff either. Interesting nonetheless.